# Adding 10 rows using lambda, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe in pandas of the following form:

```
        column
0       0
1       1
2       3
3       6
4       10
5       15
6       21
7       28
8       36
9       45
10      55
11      66
12      78
13      91
14      105
15      120
```

The task is to sum every 10 rows and create new column to put sums. Result should be like this Dataframe:

```
        num     sum        Description(no need to add this column)
0       0       0          sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0)
1       1       1          sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-1)
2       3       4          sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-2)
3       6       10         sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-3)
4       10      20         sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-4)
5       15      35         sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-5)
6       21      56         sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-6)
7       28      84         sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-7)
8       36      120        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-8)
9       45      165        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(0-9)
10      55      220        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(1-10)
11      66      285        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(2-11)
12      78      360        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(3-12)
13      91      445        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(4-13)
14      105     540        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(5-14)
15      120     645        sum of numbers of rows of column "num" by indexes(6-15)
```

Can you explain me how to do using lambda? I have tried to use shift, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *[rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).sum* with `min_periods = 1`:

```
df['sum'] = df.column.rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum()
df
```

[image]

Comment: This is good answer, thanks a lot.
But can u show the method using lamda. I know not much about lambda, so it would be better to understand how works lamda

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is much space for `lambda` to be used here, but `df.column.rolling(10, min_periods=1).agg(lambda x: x.sum())` uses lambda expression which is one way to aggregate the value in `lambda`, if you want to do more complex computation than a `sum`, this might help.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [27]: df['sum'] = df['column'].cumsum()

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
    column  sum
0        0    0
1        1    1
2        3    4
3        6   10
4       10   20
5       15   35
6       21   56
7       28   84
8       36  120
9       45  165
10      55  220
11      66  286
12      78  364
13      91  455
14     105  560
15     120  680
```

or this depending on your goals:

```
In [31]: df['sum'] = df['column'].rolling(10).sum()

In [32]: df['sum'] = df['sum'].fillna(df['column'].cumsum())

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
    column    sum
0        0    0.0
1        1    1.0
2        3    4.0
3        6   10.0
4       10   20.0
5       15   35.0
6       21   56.0
7       28   84.0
8       36  120.0
9       45  165.0
10      55  220.0
11      66  285.0
12      78  360.0
13      91  445.0
14     105  540.0
15     120  645.0
```

Or [much better solution from @Psidom - use `min_periods=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42722526/5741205)